# Is there any difference between the phrase "how is it going?" and "how is it coming?"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Could you tell if there if there is any difference between *how is something going?* and *how is something coming?* when asking how something is progressing? For example:

> How is your assignment going?
>
> How is your assignment coming?

Comment: For the second one, we would normally ask "How is your assignment coming **along**?" or "coming **on**."

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  In the TV serious "Friends" they omit the prepsitions though.

Comment: Don't tell me "Friends" is serious! I only added the preposition in the second one. In my natural English dialect, we don't say it without a preposition."

Comment: Could you please tell what dialect you speak?

Comment: I speak British English. My remark about "serious" was because I was unsure whether you made a typo, or have a misunderstanding that a 'series' is a 'serious'.

Comment: My bad! I made a typo.